# Dynamically Add/Remove Widget to list in Flutter onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

Just starting to learn Flutter and working thru a course and made a simple dice roller.  Now as a challenge to myself Im trying to upgrade the dice roller to add different types of dice.  I currently have a list of custom dice class in my Stateful widget

```
List<Dice> dice = [];
```

This is my dice class

```
class Dice extends StatelessWidget {
  Dice({@required this.diceType, @required this.onPress});

  final int diceType;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('images/d${diceType}_blank.png'),
          Text(diceType.toString()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a row of icons (using the Dice class) that will add a dice to the dice list like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: Dice(
    diceType: 4,
    onPress: () {
      setState(() {
        dice.add(Dice(
          diceType: 4,
          onPress: () {
            print('Tapped');
            setState(() {
              //What to put here to remove from dice list
            });
          },
        ));
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

The comment in the setState is what I cant seem to find.  I know I need to do something with `dice.remove()` but not sure how to reference the Expanded widget to pass it in as an object for the remove function.

Answer (score 1):

Remove a element at position [index] from a list.

```
final index = dice.length;

dice.add(
  Dice(
    diceType: 4,
    onPress: () {
      print('Tapped');
      setState(() {
        dice.removeAt(index);
      });
    },
  ),
);
```